# Alter column data type int INTO int IDENTITY

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

Table : `Test1`

```
create table test1
(
  ID int
);
```

**Note**: I have a data on this table and I don't want to lose it.

Now I want to alter the column data type to INT IDENTITY for which I am using the following script.

## My Try:

```
ALTER TABLE test1
ALTER COLUMN ID INT IDENTITY(1,1);
```

Which is throwing an error:

```
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'IDENTITY'.
```

Comment: Identity is not a data type, it's a property. AFAIK you can't set it to an existing column if it already have data.

Comment: You can't add the Identity option to an existing column.  You can add a new column to the table with INT IDENTITY(1,1).  However this will lock the table for the duration of the operation.